# Posting with ajax to an app using devise from a cross domain request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I'm trying to understand the concept of API programming.

I was able to post basic stuff ( not using devise ) in my app, like creating an article with title and description using a basic ajax post from a cross domain request (outside the app).

In the app itself I can make an ajax post to the devise url to register or sign in the user normally but the problem comes when I try to do the same thing from another application outside(cross domain request).

What I want:

I want to be able to register and sign in using across domain request via an ajax post to devise url (api).

Also, to be able to let the user know he is signed in on the outside app (not the api).

Errors:

I keep getting authentication tokens errors when I try to register or sign in using an ajax post.

Different methods that I've tried:

1) First Method:

I have tried changing in the `application` controller this line:

`protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

to

`protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`

This fixes the errors and let me register successfully and saves the information to the database (email, password).

Although I'm not sure how the sign in works, I am able to pass the sign in information without any errors using the post method from ajax to the api (but I am not able to figure out how to let the user know that he is logged in, or how to log out)

I'm afraid that this method might leave vulnerabilities to my app.

2) Second Method that I've tried:

From the cross domain app that I'm trying to post using ajax, I've added this code to the call:

```
headers: {
  'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
```

But with no success, it brings the authentication token error again `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`.

3) The third method that I've tried:

In the devise controllers for registrations and sessions I've added the following line:

```
protect_from_forgery except: :create
```

While this make it work, I'm afraid that it is the same as the first method that I've tried, it might leave vulnerabilities to my app.

My routes in the main application (api):

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations" }
match 'api/people/', to: 'people#people_get_all', via: [:get]
match 'api/people/:id', to: 'people#people_get', via: [:get]

match 'api/people/', to: 'people#create', via: [:post]
```

My javascript from the cross domain app doing the ajax post:

```
$(function(){

    $('#register_user').on('click', function(){

        var user = {
            user: {
                email: $('#email').val(),
                password: $('#password').val(),
                password_confirmation: $('#password_confirmation').val()
            }
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: user,
            success: function(newSignin){
                console.log(newSignin);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Also, everytime I try to post using the first and last method, I get the `error` function in the ajax call, even though it successfully registered the user.

I have made an example by creating a small app replicating the above. In there, you can create a person (not using devise) via ajax (which you can do from a cross domain request via an ajax post to the right urls provided here).

It has 2 other forms which post to the devise urls, one to register and the other one to sign in.

https://johhanapi.herokuapp.com/

At the moment of this post, the app is using the third method mentioned here(not counting edits).

Thank you.

Comment: use browser dev tools to inspect actual request for more clues. the term `ouside app` is suspicious if it means you are making cross domain request. If that's the case will need CORS enabled in api

Comment: @charlietfl I have the `gem 'rack-cors'` in my app, which handles that, sorry for my 'noob terms' I'm not used to them in this type of issue/case.